# ImportError: No module named bb

Tags: python, package, bitbake, openembedded

To create a helloworld `.ipk` package, as described [here](http://www.embeddedlinux.org.cn/OEManual/recipes_examples.html), I cloned `bitbake` and `OpenEmbedded` as

```
git clone git://git.openembedded.org/bitbake
git clone git://git.openembedded.org/openembedded
```

Then exported following varibales

```
export OEBASE=/media/sda3/open_env/
export PATH=$OEBASE/bitbak/ebin:$PATH
export BBPATH=$OEBASE/build:$OEBASE/openembedded
export BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE="OEBASE"
```

When I run following command I get error given below:

```
bitbake -b packages/myhelloworld/myhelloworld_0.1.bb

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/bitbake", line 35, in <module>
    import bb
ImportError: No module named bb
```

I am doing this on `ubuntu 10.04`. What I am missing here?

**EDIT:**

As given in answer, I executed following commands and getting error as given below:

```
git clone git://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core
cd openembedded-core
git clone git://git.openembedded.org/bitbake

cd ..
git checkout dylan
cd bitbake
git checkout 1.18
cd ..

. oe-init-build-env
```

Modified `build/conf/local.conf` and created `myhelloworld` dir in `openembedded-core/build/` dir and then executed

```
bitbake myhelloworld/
```

I am getting errors as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/bin/bitbake", line 34, in <module>
    import bb
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    from bb import fetch2 as fetch
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    import bb.persist_data, bb.utils
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/persist_data.py", line 35, in <module>
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ImportError: No module named pysqlite2
/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/event.py:104: RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'bb' not found while handling absolute import
  from bb.msg import BBLogFormatter
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/event.py", line 104, in print_ui_queue
    from bb.msg import BBLogFormatter
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    from bb import fetch2 as fetch
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    import bb.persist_data, bb.utils
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/persist_data.py", line 35, in <module>
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ImportError: No module named pysqlite2
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/event.py", line 104, in print_ui_queue
    from bb.msg import BBLogFormatter
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    from bb import fetch2 as fetch
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    import bb.persist_data, bb.utils
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/persist_data.py", line 35, in <module>
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ImportError: No module named pysqlite2
Pseudo is not present but is required, building this first before the main build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/bin/bitbake", line 34, in <module>
    import bb
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    from bb import fetch2 as fetch
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    import bb.persist_data, bb.utils
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/persist_data.py", line 35, in <module>
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ImportError: No module named pysqlite2
/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/event.py:104: RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'bb' not found while handling absolute import
  from bb.msg import BBLogFormatter
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/event.py", line 104, in print_ui_queue
    from bb.msg import BBLogFormatter
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    from bb import fetch2 as fetch
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    import bb.persist_data, bb.utils
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/persist_data.py", line 35, in <module>
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ImportError: No module named pysqlite2
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/event.py", line 104, in print_ui_queue
    from bb.msg import BBLogFormatter
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    from bb import fetch2 as fetch
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    import bb.persist_data, bb.utils
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/persist_data.py", line 35, in <module>
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ImportError: No module named pysqlite2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/bin/bitbake", line 34, in <module>
    import bb
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    from bb import fetch2 as fetch
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    import bb.persist_data, bb.utils
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/persist_data.py", line 35, in <module>
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ImportError: No module named pysqlite2
/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/event.py:104: RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'bb' not found while handling absolute import
  from bb.msg import BBLogFormatter
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/event.py", line 104, in print_ui_queue
    from bb.msg import BBLogFormatter
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    from bb import fetch2 as fetch
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    import bb.persist_data, bb.utils
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/persist_data.py", line 35, in <module>
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ImportError: No module named pysqlite2
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/event.py", line 104, in print_ui_queue
    from bb.msg import BBLogFormatter
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    from bb import fetch2 as fetch
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    import bb.persist_data, bb.utils
  File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/persist_data.py", line 35, in <module>
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ImportError: No module named pysqlite2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're mixing a recent bitbake with OpenEmbedded classic; please don't do that. You're also trying to setup the build environment by hand, avoid that one too. Any new development should be based on OpenEmbedded Core.

What you should do:

1. Clone the repositories.

   ```
   git clone git://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core
   cd openembedded-core
   git clone git://git.openembedded.org/bitbake
   ```

   If you want to use a certain branch, eg jethro

   ```
   git checkout jethro
   cd bitbake
   git checkout 1.28
   cd ..
   ```

   See [corresponding release branches of OE-core and bitbake](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Releases).
2. Setup the build environment:

   ```
   . oe-init-build-env
   ```
3. Configure the build.

   I.e. set the correct machine etc. in `build/conf/local.conf`.
4. Build!

   Now do you what you want, e.g. any of:

   ```
   bitbake core-image-minimal
   bitbake myehelloworld
   ```

Update: Note that the last release (of `Poky`, that officially was tested against `Ubuntu 10.04` was `Dylan`). Later releases might very well have issues on that host, I'd recommend to update to a newer LTS-release.

Update 2: Your new error says `ImportError: No module named pysqlite2`. Bitbake will first look for `sqlite3`. Install that on your build-host `apt-get install libsqlite3-dev`

Comment: Thank you so much! But I am getting same error for this clone too: `File "/media/sda3/open_env/openembedded-core/bitbake/bin/bitbake", line 31, in <module>` for `import bb`. I tried it on `Ubuntu 10.04` for now.

Comment: First, remove `bitbake` if it's installed from Ubuntu's repos. 2nd, remove `bb` from your  pip-install. If you still have issues, what versions of bitbake and OE-core are you running? Regarding your `myhelloworld`  dir, I'd recommend creating your own layer for that.

Comment: Could you paste the error you get using `bitbake` from git anyway, just to ensure what it is. I don't have such an old Ubuntu box available. Please paste it somewhere.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please, read the error message, this one was _not_ the same as your earlier one. Now it's a general python module that isn't installed.

Comment: `python-pysqlite2 is already the newest version.` No luck with the errors yet.

Comment: Well, run `python` by hand, and try to `import pysqlite2` does it work? Are you running a straight python from  `Ubuntu`, or are you adding things through `pip`? Run without `pip` installed packages.

Comment: When I run `python` and run `import pysqlite2` it gives `ImportError: No module named pysqlite2`. I don't know anything about `python` or 'pip'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108261/discussion-between-anders-and-ntn).

Answer (score -3):

You are missing the bb module. You need to install all dependencies from your requirements file or manually with pip.
This may help you.
http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing/#requirements-for-installing-packages

Comment: I ran `pip install bb`, and it `Successfully installed bb`, event then I am getting same error

Comment: While installing one of the requirement, I am getting this error `VersionConflict: (argparse 1.4.0 (/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('argparse==1.2.1'))`, How to solve this?

Comment: No. The issue is that bitbake is installed / used in the wrong way, together with OE.